# find two strings in a string array that their length together equals to 6

Tags: c#, algorithm

What I have :

```
string[] array = new string[] { "Hello", "Please", "Help", "Me", "Thanks" };
```

Now I want filter this array to find two string that their length together equals to 6:
`{ "Help", "Me" }`.

Thanks.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: thanks for quick response. yes i tried Array.Find but is not what i want

Comment: Solve an easier problem. Suppose you have an array of positive integers. Can you find two that sum to six?

Comment: @EricLippert I don't think that it is the easiest way to model it... I think that it would be easier if he thought of the cartesian product `L(s)xL(s)` where `L` is a function that calculate the length of the string `s`

Comment: please post a example. im new to c#. thanks again

Comment: what if there are more then 2? suppose you also had "you" and "her" in the array, what would you expect to return?

Comment: well i want to create a new string array from them so it can return more than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sorts the `array` by length of the strings and starts searching from the first string (`min = 0`) and the last one (`max = array.Length - 1`).

If the sum of the lengths if less than 6, advance `min` index.
If the sum of the lengths if greater than 6, reduce `max` index.
If the sum of the lengths are equals to 6, then you have the words.

if `min` index reach `max` index then there are no words.

```
public string[] Words(string[] array)
{
    var sorted = array.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ToArray();

    int min = 0;
    int max = sorted.Length - 1;

    while (min < max)
    {
        int length = sorted[min].Length + sorted[max].Length;

        if (length < 6) min++;
        else if (length > 6) max--;
        else return new string[] { sorted[min], sorted[max] };
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm. sorry i dont have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Can be done in a single LINQ query...

```
array = array.Where(o => 6 - o.Length >= 0 && array.Any(n => n.Length == 6 - o.Length)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Note that this approach is quadratic whereas [Arturo's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36014192/18192) is nlogn.

Comment: @Brian Indeed. I did consider the time complexity at the time of writing. I was however just being cocky by producing a one liner ;-)